# Query facebook wall of a specific profile

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I need to post on a website the wall notifications of a Facebook group, the group and the website belong to the same entity.

I've looked at many of the options available, but I would apreciate if someone with a bit Facebook developing experience told me what is the best path (most straighforward).

The website is not intented to interact with Facebook in any other way, there would exist no Facebook login button, and this one wall would be the only one being consulted.

I've looked at the possibility of grabbing an rss feed from the wall, but that option doesn't seem to exist.

The website is being done with asp.net (c#).

Answer (score 1):

And Social Plug-ins are Exactly for that purpose. For your requirement you can use Live Stream Plugin. Look Here:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/[enter link description here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your choice of getting an RSS feed of the group activity, you can use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/) to get the activity as JSON objects, at which point you can render them to your page.

Comment: Everything I see using the Graph API assumes you will be retriving the user's data, but what I needed is a specific user's data. Is there no way to avoid the all "go to FB for a login and handle the callback routine" ?

Comment: @SynBiotik: You can access the [feed of a group](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/), which I think is exactly what you want to do. You'll just need the group id, provided that the group wall is public. If it's not public, you'll need to set up [authorization](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#auth).